# Primefaces selectOneMenu keyboard search settings

Tags: search, primefaces, keyboard, selectonemenu

Basically the following issue describes exactly my problem:
http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=5247

It is marked as "fixed" for Primefaces 5.1 which I'm using. Sadly I cannot see how this is fixed or should be used now.

The problem in my own words:

I'm using a `<p:selectOneMenu>` for a (long) list of countries. When the component is selected you can navigate by typing on your keyboard.

Let's say you want to find "Nicaragua" and start typing. After typing "n" "New Zealand" is displayed. Then you type "i" and expect to find entries starting with "Ni...". Instead the "i" leads to display "India".

So everytime a new character is typed, the search starts from the beginning.
I would like to customize/use any kind of settings or parameters.

Using `<h:selectOneMenu>` (which works as desired) is not an option for design/css reasons.

Any help or suggestions to improve the question appreciated!

Comment: [PrimeFaces showcase for selectOneMenu](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml) works fine...

Comment: I don't want to use a filter as in the advanced example. And in the grouping example there seems to be some timeout before a new search is executed. Not sure about that, but it's not exactly fitting my needs.

Comment: I have a selectOneMenu populated with java.util.Currency (+ converter) and it's not very friendly if you don't want to use the mouse. For example, selecting EUR is very difficult. It works fine if you click and then start typing. autoComplete is nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `filterMatchMode="contains"`. It can helps. Just add to the `<p:selectOneMenu filterMatchMode="contains">`.